# Consumer-Facing Websites or Apps using Bing Maps

Tags: web-mapping, mobile, bing-maps

I'm researching Bing Maps for use in a consumer-facing website/app. Is there a resource that lists existing websites/apps that are using Bing Maps for the basemap? I've found examples of websites, but haven't had much luck finding example of mobile apps. I've primarily referenced Bing Maps (http://blogs.bing.com/maps), but was hoping there might be a better way to search for this type of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a published list of apps that use Bing Maps. Here are a few that are using the JavaScript control in cross platform mobile apps (some of the links to the iOS apps may have changed):

- FlySmart: Be an Airport Insider for iOS, Android and Blackberry. Includes in-airport navigation using Bing Maps and Venue Maps of airports

Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sapient.ionos.flysmart.android

iOS: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flysmart-be-airport-insider/id525407032?mt=8

Blackberry: http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/113529/?lang=en

- Kayak:

Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kayak.android

WP: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/kayak/b26c5aae-dea7-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8

- Choice Hotels:

iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/choice-hotels/id509342785?mt=8

Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.choicehotels.android

- United App:

WP: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/united/e70dd5c6-dcd1-47e6-a3ab-3fc752aa33ed

- MyLincoln Mobile

iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mylincoln-mobile/id568936180?mt=8

Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lincoln.mlm

- Bing Get Me There

iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/bing-get-methere/id544834191?mt=8

WP: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/bing-get-me-there/744d9d43-ee65-e011-81d2-78e7d1fa76f8

- Weather Network

BlackBerry: http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/55227

- AutoScout24 (Germany)

WP: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/autoscout24/6ac82e62-2c05-e011-9264-00237de2db9e

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for.Thanks so much for your help! Much appreciated.